# Render unstanitized HTML with ClojureScript+Sablono

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript, om

I have a dataset saved in a global atom (as per the typical design pattern in ClojureScript SPA's), and I know that the data is safe (I manually typed it in - its just a list of quotes that I'm rendering randomly one per pageload).

However, the quotes contain basic HTML tags like `<i>` and characters such as `&mdash`. I'm using [sablono](https://github.com/r0man/sablono) to render the data in HTML like so:

```
(defcomponentk quote
  [[:data quotes]]
  (render [_]
      (let [quote (rand-nth quotes)]
        (html
         [:section
          [:blockquote {:id "quote"}
           [:header (om/build citation quote)]
           (map #(vector :p %) (:quote quote))]]))))
```

`(:quote quote)` is a vector of strings, each string is a paragraph of the quote (thus I map the `:p` tag over it).

How do I tell Sablono to render the strings as HTML and not as raw text?

The only thing I can think of is mapping `sablono.core/html` over each string, but I can't get that to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React offers `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as an option for its components. If you are using Sablono with Om you can do something like this:

```clj
(om.dom/div #js {:dangerouslySetInnerHTML #js {:__html "<b>Bold!</b>"}})
```

More information here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojurescript/DXzHx3vkszo
https://github.com/r0man/sablono/issues/36